# montar elemento HTML com vanilla JS, não consigo listar todos os elementos do JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

Aonde está o erro no meu código?

Não estou conseguindo listar todos os nomes cada um em uma `<li>` diferente, no meu `console.log(items[i].name)` todos os nomes do JSON aparecem, porém na hora de criar o elemento html ele só pega o ultimo nome.

```js
const myList = fetch('people.json')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(result => {
  const items = result.data;

  for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    let people = document.getElementById("people");

    console.log(items[i].name)
    
    const markup = `
      <li>
        ${items[i].name}
      </li>
    `;

    people.innerHTML = markup;
  }
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log("Erro");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você esqueceu um `+`.

```
people.innerHTML += markup;
```

em todo caso, sugiro pelo menos que remova o `.innerHTML = markup` do seu laço, esta operação é muito custosa.

```
let markup = "";
let people = document.getElementById("people");
for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  console.log(items[i].name);
  markup += `
    <li>
      ${items[i].name}
    </li>
  `;
}
people.innerHTML = markup;
```

E por fim estou em uma Vibe de usar VueJS para tudo ;D

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    passo: "Iniciando a aplicação",
    nomes: [ "Fulano", "Ciclano", "Beltrano" ]
  }
});

// inserir novo nome apos 2 segundos.
window.setTimeout(function () {
  app.passo = "inserindo novo nome apos 2 segundos.";
  app.nomes.push("Toby Mosque");
}, 2000);

// atualizar toda a lista apos 4 segundos
window.setTimeout(function () {
  app.passo = "atualizando toda a lista apos 4 segundos.";
  app.nomes = [ "Eric", "Toby Mosque" ]
}, 4000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>passo: {{passo}}</p>
  <ul v-for="(nome, indice) in nomes">
    <li>{{indice}} - {{nome}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Caramba que vacilooo por causa de um +, muito obrigadoooo. Esqueci que do jeito que tava ao criar um ele apaga o anterior e por isso aparece o ultimo nome da lista. VLWW vou seguir sua dica tb.

Comment: @Erick atualizei a resposta, talvez lhe interrese.

Comment: Legal, eu queria começar com Vue mas fiz um curso de angular4 rescente então vou tentar brincar com ele. Mas nesse caso especifico tem que ser só JS mesmo.  Mas com ctz vai me servir de estudo seu exemplo. Obrigado mesmo.

Comment: @Erick o que acho legal no Vue, é que você consegue usar ele para resolver problemas pequenos e grandes, assim como pode utiliza-lo em sistemas já existentes, e claro pode ir adotando e aprendendo aos poucos. Já com o angular, o buraco é mais embaixo ;D

Comment: nesse json aonde tenho os nomes, tenho um item chamado positivo que possui um valor, qual a melhor forma em JS para listar em primeiro quem tem o maior valor no campo positivo?  talvez um .map?

Comment: @Eric com um sort: `items = items.sort(function (itemA, itemB) { return itemB.positivo - itemA.positivo;  })`

Comment: Genio rs, obrigado.

Comment: Vue.js ++ :) também estou infetado

Comment: @Sergio se você também está infectado, então fico mais tranquilo ;D

Comment: Já agora, sugestão: `people.innerHTML = items.map(({name}) => \`<li>
      ${name}
    </li>\`).join('');`

Comment: @Sergio arrow function com atribuição dos argumentos a partir do nome das propriedades do objeto, me parece um pouco confuso ;D. Para ser sinsero, é a primeira vez que vejo ao do gênero.

Comment: @TobiasMesquita é, a sintaxe fica meio estranha no inicio, mas ajuda a poupar o loop `for`

Comment: Acho que eu acabaria usando o `item => item.name` ao invés de `({name}) => name` (que dá no mesmo).